# Issue with unrecognized option in ANT

Tags: java, windows, ant

I have used quite a bit of resources to try to understand why I am gettting the following error when attempting to run ant from the command line:

```
Unrecognized option: -dant.home=C:\ANT\1.7.0
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

ERROR: The file is either empty or does not contain the valid choices.
```

To give a little insight, I have my path to include %JAVA_HOME% and then %ANT_HOME%\bin.
One of the things that I cannot do is run as administrator to update the system variables, only the user variables. Has anyone run into this before? Thank you for the help!

EDIT: For an update, I uncommented the @echo off at the top of ant.bat and ran ant.bat to show what unrecognized option occured below:

```
C:\ANT\1.7.0\bin>if not "" == "" goto runantwithjikes

C:\ANT\1.7.0\bin>if "no" == "no" goto runantnoclasspath

C:\ANT\1.7.0\bin>"C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin\java.exe"  -classpath "C:\ANT\1.7.0\li
b\ant-launcher.jar" "-dant.home=C:\ANT\1.7.0" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.launch
er
Unrecognized option: -dant.home=C:\ANT\1.7.0
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

UPDATE:
I think that after doing more research, it has to relate to the classpath variable trying to resolve the launcher.jar file. If anyone has encountered this in windows that would be awesome if they had an idea of what next to do. Also, I am not using a custom ant library.

UPDATE:
I decided to include a little debugging into this page. Hopefully that is okay, I echo out the rest of the batch file after line 130:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>ant
DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG Attempting to execute an Ant java process
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if "no" == "no" goto runantnoclasspath

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java.exe"  -cla
sspath "C:\ANT\1.7.0\lib\ant-launcher.jar" "-dant.home=C:\ANT\1.7.0" org.apache.
tools.ant.launch.launcher
Unrecognized option: -dant.home=C:\ANT\1.7.0
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>rem check the error code of the ant build

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if not "Windows_NT" == "windows_nt" goto onerror

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>rem windows 9x way of checking the error code.  it matches v
ia brute force.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>for %i in (1 10 100) do set err%i=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>set err1=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>set err10=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>set err100=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>for %i in (0 1 2) do if errorlevel %i00 set err100=%i

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 000 set err100=0

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 100 set err100=1

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 200 set err100=2

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if 0 == 2 goto onerror200

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if 0 == 0 set err100=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>for %i in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do if errorlevel %i0 set err
10=%i

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 00 set err10=0

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 10 set err10=1

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 20 set err10=2

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 30 set err10=3

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 40 set err10=4

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 50 set err10=5

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 60 set err10=6

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 70 set err10=7

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 80 set err10=8

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 90 set err10=9

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if "" == "" if 0 == 0 set err10=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>for %i in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do if errorlevel %i set err1
=%i

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 0 set err1=0

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 1 set err1=1

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 2 set err1=2

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 3 set err1=3

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 4 set err1=4

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 5 set err1=5

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 6 set err1=6

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 7 set err1=7

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 8 set err1=8

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if errorlevel 9 set err1=9

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>goto onerrorend

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>set ant_error=1

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>for %i in (1 10 100) do set err%i=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>set err1=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>set err10=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>set err100=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>rem bug id 32069: resetting an undefined env variable change
s the errorlevel.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if not "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java.exe
" == "" set _javacmd=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if not "" == "" set ant_cmd_line_args=

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if "1" == "0" goto mainend

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>rem set the return code if we are not in nt.  we can only se
t

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>rem a value of 1, but it's better than nothing.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if not "Windows_NT" == "windows_nt" echo 1   1>nul  | choice
 /n /c:1

ERROR: The file is either empty or does not contain the valid choices.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>rem set the errorlevel if we are running nt.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>if "Windows_NT" == "windows_nt" color 00

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>goto omega
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>
```

Of particular concern to me is this part:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java.exe"  -cla
sspath "C:\ANT\1.7.0\lib\ant-launcher.jar" "-dant.home=C:\ANT\1.7.0" org.apache.
tools.ant.launch.launcher
```

I read on the manual for apache that you should not change the class path, so I left it alone.

Comment: Please give me more information. Do you try to include a custom ant lib?

Comment: Hey thanks for checking, I have not included a custom ant lib. I have done the regular installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-d` switch turns on debugging (it is a synonym for `-debug`).

It looks like you wanted the `-D` switch, which defines a value for a property i.e.,

> `-Dant.home=C:\ANT\1.7.0`

You can see all the command line options by typing:

> `ant -help`

Comment: Thank you for the information, oddly when I type into the command line ant -help it still reproduces the same unrecognized option. I am unsure why -D comes up though still.